# Proof by Cases - if $3$ does not divide $n$, then $3$ divides $n^3 - 2n^2 + 5n - 10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Proof by Cases - if $3$ does not divide $n$, then $3$ divides $n^3 - 2n^2 + 5n - 10$

How do go about using proofs for this question? I know I need to first find all possible cases where $3$ divides $n$, isn't that $0,1,2,3$?

But then what?

Comment: Two cases, (i) the remainder when we divide $n$ by $3$ is $1$ and (ii) the remainder when we divide $n$ by $3$ is $2$. Now what you do depends on what background you have. In case (i) you can let $n=3k+1$, and calculate. Similar for Case (ii).

Comment: what if n is like 9? Isn't 3 a remainder also?

Comment: In that case $3$ divides $n$, and you are supposed to show what happens when $3$ does not divide $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Two cases: (calculations being made in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$)

$n=1$:

$1^3-2.1^2+5.1-10=-6=0$

$n=2$:

$2^3-2.2^2+5.2-10=0$

Comment: How does this solution take into account the given assumption that 3 does not divide n? Also how does this then go on to prove that 3 in fact divides n3−2n2+5n−10?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write out the equation modulo 3 to get
$$n^3 - 2n^2 + 5n - 10\mod 3 \equiv n^3 - 2n^2 + 2n - 1\mod 3$$

Now, divide into 2 cases, where $n\equiv 1\mod 3$ and $n\equiv 2\mod 3$. (These correspond to remainder 1 and 2 resp.) Try to take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $3 \not | n$, we have to show that 
$3|n^3-2n^2+5n-10$. $\implies$
 $3|n^3-2n^2+2n-1$

$n^3-1-2n^2+2n=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)-2n(n-1)=(n-1)(n^2-n+1)$ .

we know that $3$ is prime so either $3|(n-1)$ or $3|(n^2-n+1)$

case(1):  $n=3k+1$ then $3|(n-1)$.

case(2): $n=3k$ obviously it's not true because given  that $3 \not | n$

case(3):  $n=3k+2$ then   $3|(n^2-n+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Ever number is 0, 1, or 2 mod 3. This means that it is 0, 1, or 2 more than a multiple of 3. In terms of divisive kitty, it doesn't matter if we are talking about 1, or 13, or 300001. They are all 3k+1. Try checking for just 1 and 2